# Error trapping for a missing data source in a Spring MVC / Spring JDBC web app

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, error-detection

I have written a web app that uses Spring MVC libraries and Spring JDBC to connect to an Oracle DB. (I don't use any ORM type libraries as I create stored procedures on Oracle that do my stuff and I'm quite happy with that.)
I use a connection pool to Oracle managed by the Tomcat container

The app generally works absolutely fine by the way!

BUT...
I noticed the other day when I tried to set up the app on another Tomcat instance that I had forgotten to configure the connection pool and obviously the app could not get hold of an org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource object, so it crashed.

I define the pool params in the tomcat "**context.conf**"

In my "**web.xml**" I have:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- Map *everything* to appServlet -->
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/ora1</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And I have a Spring "**servlet-context.xml**" where JNDI is used to map the data source object provided by the connection pool to a Spring bean with the ID of "dataSource":

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ora1"
    resource-ref="true" />
```

**Here's the question: Where do I trap the case where the database cannot be accessed for whatever reason?**

I don't want the user to see a yard-and-a-half of Java stack trace in their browser, rather a nicer message that tells them there is a database problem etc.
It seems that my app tries to configure the "dataSource" bean (in "servlet-context.xml") before any code has tested it can actually provide a dataSource object from the pool?!

Maybe I'm not fully understanding exactly what is going on in these stages of the app firing up ...

Thanks for any advice!

**UPDATE: FIXED! Let Spring configure the MVC stuff, but get a data source via the Controller**

I took the `jndi-lookup` line out of the `servlet-context.xml` file, and added another class, below.
I called the getJndiDataSource method from my Controller when I wanted to connect to the database, and needed the data source, trapping all errors in the obtaining and using of the datasource object.

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DataSrcConfig {

   public static DataSource getJndiDataSource() throws NamingException{

       Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
       DataSource ds = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ora1");

       return ds;
   }
}
```

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there though - it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Comment: I think the point I'm driving at is that it seems to me that it is the Spring container that is throwing the error in this situation, as it tries to initialize - not the code I have written and have direct control over...

Comment: I have a feeling that something needs "decoupling" here: For my MVC app to work it depends on a data source object as it initializes. I suppose it is the presence of the data source object that allows the model part of the system (i.e. Model, View, Controller) to come into existence.
But without the model's initialization the system is broken and I can't use the controller to change the view to a nice error message.

I have a suspicion that the initialization of the app should not depend on the data source being available and the the data source object should be requested by the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have a some suggestions:

1. Have you tried defining the datasource object in Spring instead of in Tomcat? That way you'll have all your configuration parameters in one place.
2. Do you use the [validationQuery](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) on DBCP to test the connections?
3. If there is a StackTrace, can you catch it and display a friendlier message?

(Also, take a look at [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) which is a faster pool implementation).

Comment: (1) No, the cxn pool is used by other apps, so I thought best let Tomcat administer it? (2) No - I need to check this out, thanks. (3) This is actually my question - how do I trap this error?

Comment: Looking at your comment above, if Spring is throwing an Exception while it's initializing, when the web app starts. Then you can fix your connection parameters before the users start using the site?

Comment: Yes ... as I say under normal circumstances there isn't a problem, but if the database goes down (I don't control the DB) I would like my app to fail gracefully. The fact that I noticed this messy stack trace echoed to the browser whilst I had forgotten to configure the `context.conf` in Tomcat is just one possible reason the connection pool could fail to hand out a data source object to my app. This is a reason for failure that is within my control to fix. But there are many reasons the DB may not be available and most are **not** within my control to fix.